# Push notifications for a salesforce iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, salesforce, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to evaluate the ways in which I could implement push notification for a `salesforce` iPhone app that I am going to create. Options I am going to explore are `Urban Airship` or `Salesforce's Streaming API`. Does anyone have any recommendation (Best solutions available) or does anyone know of any other ways. Also please guide me on the steps to achieve push notification for an app that gets data from `salesforce.com` using `salesforce.com's rest API`.

Comment: Do you mean in your own app or in the existing Appstore app of  Salesforce. Because you can't just add push notification to apps, you need to have to source code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant in an app that I am building that be using salesforce REST API to get data. when ever certain data changes in salesforce I would like to display a notification on the app that I am creating

Comment: Well the check for changes should be server side, then the server can send the Push notification, either via Urban Airship or directly to the Apple APNS server. For create and receiving push notification see the Apple [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)

Comment: I am familiar with iPhone development. I would like more guidance on how to send messages to Apple APNS. Will salesforce's Streming API help me achieve that? Or is there any other way. I more interested in finding our the options on the server side work that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the Spring 14 release, Salesforce supports Apple ( APNS ) and Google ( GCM ) mobile push notifications via the Connected Apps framework. Please check the Mobile Push Notifications Tip Sheet on Developer Force for more information: http://www2.developerforce.com/en/mobile/resources